# Как получить коллекцию объектов вместо коллекции внешних ключей?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, entity-framework, linq

Я использую: PostgreSQL, EntityFrameworkCore, Npgsql, LINQ
Есть таблица, скажем, фильмов, в которой есть столбец с массивом из ID жанров и есть таблица с жанрами.

Таблицы:

```
//Таблица Genres
id   integer
name text

//Таблица Movies
id        integer
name      text
genres_id integer[]
```

Сущности:

```
public class Genre{
    [Key, Column("id")]
    public int    Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Movie{
    [Key, Column("id")]
    public int     Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string  Name { get; set; }

    [Column("genres_ids", TypeName = "integer[]")]
    public int[] Genres { get; set; } //хотелось бы Genre[]
}
```

Возможно ли как-то настроить БД и/или контекст так, чтобы в коде работать с полем Genres как с массивом `Genre`, а не числовым массивом? Чтобы не приходилось делать лишние запросы, когда нужно получить коллекцию жанров конкретного фильма.

Answer (score 2):

Массивы сейчас не могут быть внешними ключами. Патч добавляющий [соответствующий функционал](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/17/1252/) уже есть, и пока даже есть слабая надежда что будет принят в postgresql 11. Окончательно будет известно в апреле, сейчас как раз последний коммитфест для релиза 11 версии.

Запрос сформировать можно. Вообще рекурсивные запросы превращают SQL в Тьюринг-полный язык. Для задачи достать по массиву данные из другой таблицы подходящей функцией является `unnest` и оператор `any`. Ну, например, подзапросом достанем все жанры и упакуем в json массив:

```
select f.id, f.name
    (select json_agg(json_build_object('id', g.id, 'name', g.name)) 
        from genres g 
        where g.id = any(f.genres_array)
    ) as genre
from films f
```

Насчёт вашего кода ничем не могу помочь по очевидной причине - вы не указали никакой конкретики.

Comment: по поводу конкретики, обновил вопрос)

Comment: Вы всё ещё не добавили ничего конкретного. Хоть элементарно какой это вообще язык. Потому что очевидно, что речь не о SQL. Нет там классов. Не говоря о используемых библиотеках - ведь последний вопрос у вас явно про какой-то очередной orm.

Comment: я пишу на C#, с помощью EntityFrameworkCore и LINQ. Просто я думал есть общее независимое от языка решение, как по запросу вернуть строку, полем которой будет коллекция из другой таблицы.

Comment: посредством ForeignKey мы, вроде как можем вместо id в другой таблице возвращать строку из этой таблицы. думал возможно ли подобное с коллекцией

Comment: Foreign key - это constraint, ограничение валидирующее ссылочную целостность данных. Не меньше, но и не больше. К читающим запросам отношения не имеет абсолютно никакого.

Comment: то есть в моём случае надо искать решение конкретно под мой язык? как лучше сделать? добавить тег языка и уточнить вопрос или создать новый?

Comment: Если говорить про всякое orm - специфично только для конкретной библиотеки. Я по решёткам не отвечу. На уровне SQL - есть запрос и результат, всегда выглядящий таблицей. Никаких классов, коллекций и прочего.